# How do I finish a recursive binary search in fortran?

Tags: recursion, fortran, binary-search

I am trying to find the smallest index containing the value i in a sorted array. If this i value is not present I want -1 to be returned. I am using a binary search recursive subroutine. The problem is that I can't really stop this recursion and I get lot of answers(one right and the rest wrong). And sometimes I get an error called "segmentation fault: 11" and I don't really get any results.

I've tried to delete this call random_number since I already have a sorted array in my main program, but it did not work.

```
 program main
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable      :: A(:)
  real                      :: MAX_VALUE
  integer                   :: i,j,n,s, low, high
  real                      :: x

  N= 10                !size of table
  MAX_VALUE = 10

  allocate(A(n))

  s = 5          ! searched value
  low = 1        ! lower limit
  high = n       ! highest limit


  !generate random table of numbers (from 0 to 1000)
  call Random_Seed
  do i=1, N
     call Random_Number(x)  !returns random x >= 0 and <1
   A(i)= anint(MAX_VALUE*x)
  end do

 call bubble(n,a)
 print *,' '
 write(*,10) (a(i),i=1,N)
 10 format(10i6)

 call bsearch(A,n,s,low,high)

 deallocate(A)

end program main
```

The sort subroutine:

```
subroutine sort(p,q)

    implicit none
    integer(kind=4), intent(inout)      :: p, q
    integer(kind=4)                  :: temp

    if (p>q) then
       temp = p
       p = q
       q = temp
    end if
    return
end subroutine sort
```

The bubble subroutine:

```
subroutine bubble(n,arr)

 implicit none
 integer(kind=4), intent(inout)        :: n
 integer(kind=4), intent(inout)        :: arr(n)
 integer(kind=4)                       :: sorted(n)
 integer                               :: i,j

do i=1, n
   do j=n, i+1, -1
      call sort(arr(j-1), arr(j))
   end do
end do
return

end subroutine bubble

recursive subroutine bsearch(b,n,i,low,high)

   implicit none
   integer(kind=4)       ::    b(n)
   integer(kind=4)       ::    low, high
   integer(kind=4)       ::    i,j,x,idx,n
   real(kind=4)          ::    r

   idx = -1

   call random_Number(r)
   x = low + anint((high - low)*r)

   if (b(x).lt.i) then
   low = x + 1
   call bsearch(b,n,i,low,high)

   else if (b(x).gt.i) then
      high = x - 1
      call bsearch(b,n,i,low,high)
   else
   do j = low, high
    if (b(j).eq.i) then
       idx = j
       exit
    end if
    end do
  end if

 ! Stop if high = low
    if (low.eq.high) then
    return
   end if

   print*, i, 'found at index ', idx
   return

   end subroutine bsearch
```

The goal is to get the same results as my linear search. But I'am getting either of these answers.

Sorted table:

```
     1     1     2     4     5     5     6     7     8    10

       5 found at index            5
       5 found at index           -1
       5 found at index           -1
```

or if the value is not found

```
   2     2     3     4     4     6     6     7     8     8  

   Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran], you will get more attention.

Comment: Please make a complete compilable program out of it. Also I suspect that some declarations are missing in the `bsearch` routine, please explicitly add them (and also `implicit none` so none are forgotten. Which value do you use for `r` when removing the `random_number`.

Comment: When I removed random_number I also deleted r because I had the variable x in my main program.

Comment: It is good to have explicit interfaces for your subroutines. Put them in a module or make them internal (after the `contains` and before `end program`). That will enable some compiler checks. Also, when you have similar crashes, you *always* should enable compiler checks like `gfortran -Wall -fcheck=all -g -fbacktrace` or the equivalent for your compiler. It is extremely important.

Comment: When I put the subroutines in a module called mod1 and use this module in my main program I get this message: Can't open module file ‘mod1.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory compilation terminated. I get an error for all variables inside the module too. Do you know what this could be?

Comment: Your current code cannot be compiled. It gives many and many errors compile time errors. You must show the **actual code**, a [mcve]. Also, regarding the problem with modules, 
I can't say anything without the complete code and the complete error message.

Comment: I have added the subroutines to sort the array and now it's possible to compile. Sorry about that.

Comment: That's true. I put N=5 before allocate and now it doesn't give me a general error when compiling. The 'Segmentation fault: 11 ' error only comes now if the value is not found. I added the bsearch subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a two issues causing your recursive search routine `bsearch` to either stop with unwanted output, or result in a segmentation fault. Simply following the execution logic of your program at the hand of the examples you provided, elucidate the matter:

**1) value present and found, unwanted output**
First, consider the first example where array `b` contains the value `i=5` you are searching for (value and index pointed out with `||` in the first two lines of the code block below). Using the notation `Rn` to indicate the the `n`'th level of recursion, `L` and `H` for the lower- and upper bounds and `x` for the current index estimate, a given run of your code could look something like this:

```
b(x): 1     1     2     4    |5|    5     6     7     8    10
x:    1     2     3     4    |5|    6     7     8     9    10
R0:   L                                         x          H
R1:   Lx                                  H
R2:         L                       x     H

    5 found at index            5
    5 found at index           -1
    5 found at index           -1
```

In R0 and R1, the tests `b(x).lt.i` and `b(x).gt.i` in `bsearch` work as intended to reduce the search interval. In R2 the `do`-loop in the `else` branch is executed, `idx` is assigned the correct value and this is printed - as intended. *However*, a `return` statement is now encountered which will [return control to the calling program unit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnb3/index.html) - in this case that is first R1(!) where execution will resume after the `if-else if-else` block, thus printing a message to screen with the initial value of `idx=-1`. The same happens upon returning from R0 to the main program. This explains the (unwanted) output you see.

**2) value not present, segmentation fault**
Secondly, consider the example resulting in a segmentation fault. Using the same notation as before, a possible run could look like this:

```
b(x): 2     2     3     4     4     6     6     7     8     8
x:    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10
R0:   L                 x                                   H
R1:                           L                       x     H
R2:                           L     x           H
R3:                          LxH
R4:                           H     xL
.
.
.

Segmentation fault: 11
```

In R0 to R2 the search interval is again reduced as intended. However, in R3 the logic fails. Since the search value `i` is not present   in array `b`, one of the `.lt.` or `.gt.` tests will always evaluate to `.true.`, meaning that the test for `low .eq. high` to   terminate a search is never reached. From this point onwards, the logic is no longer valid (e.g. `high` can be smaller than `low`) and   the code will continue deepening the level of recursion until the call stack gets too big and a segmentation fault occurs.

These explained the main logical flaws in the code. A possible inefficiency is the use of a `do`-loop to find the lowest index containing a searched for value. Consider a case where the value you are looking for is e.g. `i=8`, and that it appears in the last position in your array, as below. Assume further that by chance, the first guess for its position is `x = high`. This implies that your code will immediately branch to the `do`-loop, where in effect a linear search is done of very nearly the entire array, to find the final result `idx=9`. Although correct, the intended binary search rather becomes a linear search, which could result in reduced performance.

```
b(x): 2     2     3     4     4     6     6     7    |8|    8
x:    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    |9|    10
R0:   L                                                     xH

    8 found at index            9
```

#### Fixing the problems

At the very least, you should move the `low .eq. high` test to the start of the `bsearch` routine, so that recursion stops before invalid bounds can be defined (you then need an additional test to see if the search value was found or not). Also, notify about a successful search right after it occurs, i.e. after the equality test in your `do`-loop, or the additional test just mentioned. This still does not address the inefficiency of a possible linear search.

All taken into account, you are probably better off reading up on algorithms for finding a *"leftmost"* index (e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure_for_finding_the_leftmost_element) or look at a [tried and tested implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/bisect.py) - both examples here use iteration instead of recursion, perhaps another improvement, but the same principles apply) and adapt that to Fortran, which could look something like this (only showing new code, `...`refer to existing code in your examples):

```
module mod_search
  implicit none
  contains
    ! Function that uses recursive binary search to look for `key` in an
    ! ordered `array`. Returns the array index of the leftmost occurrence
    ! of `key` if present in `array`, and -1 otherwise
    function search_ordered (array, key) result (idx)
      integer, intent(in) :: array(:)
      integer, intent(in) :: key
      integer :: idx

      ! find left most array index that could possibly hold `key`
      idx = binary_search_left(1, size(array))

      ! if `key` is not found, return -1
      if (array(idx) /= key) then
        idx = -1
      end if

      contains

        ! function for recursive reduction of search interval
        recursive function binary_search_left(low, high) result(idx)
          integer, intent(in) :: low, high
          integer             :: idx
          real                :: r

          if (high <= low ) then
            ! found lowest possible index where target could be
            idx = low
          else
            ! new guess
            call random_number(r)
            idx = low + floor((high - low)*r)
            ! alternative: idx = low + (high - low) / 2

            if (array(idx) < key) then
              ! continue looking to the right of current guess
              idx = binary_search_left(idx + 1, high)
            else
              ! continue looking to the left of current guess (inclusive)
              idx = binary_search_left(low, idx)
            end if
          end if
        end function binary_search_left

    end function search_ordered

    ! Move your routines into a module
    subroutine sort(p,q)
       ...
    end subroutine sort

    subroutine bubble(n,arr)
      ...
    end subroutine bubble
end module mod_search

! your main program
program main
  use mod_search, only : search_ordered, sort, bubble    ! <---- use routines from module like so
  implicit none
  ...

  ! Replace your call to bsearch() with the following:
  ! call bsearch(A,n,s,low,high)
  i = search_ordered(A, s)
  if (i /= -1) then
    print *, s, 'found at index ', i
  else
    print *, s, 'not found!'
  end if
  ...
end program main
```

Finally, depending on your actual use case, you could also just consider using the Fortran [intrinsic procedure `minloc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MINLOC.html) saving you the trouble of implementing all this functionality yourself. In this case, it can be done by making the following modification in your main program:

```
! i = search_ordered(a, s)  ! <---- comment out this line
j = minloc(abs(a-s), dim=1) ! <---- replace with these two
i = merge(j, -1, a(j) == s)
```

where `j` returned from `minloc` will be the lowest index in the array `a` where `s` may be found, and [`merge`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MERGE.html) is used to return `j` when `a(j) == s` and `-1` otherwise.